# T[]の値をキーとしたGroupBy

Tags: c#

Linq - group by using the elements inside an array property
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724862/7882280

int配列をキーとするようなものは見つかりましたが、オブジェクトの配列でGroupByをするようなものは見つかりませんでした。
上記を参考に実装してみたものが以下になります。
(Utf8Jsonを使用しています。)

```
public class AAA
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var group = GetValues().GroupBy(x => x, new ArrayComparer<AAA>()).ToArray();

        // Count:200000 Json:[{ "Key":1,"Value":"a"},{ "Key":2,"Value":"bb"}]
        // Count:100000 Json:[{ "Key":1,"Value":"a"},{ "Key":2,"Value":"ccc"}]
        // Count:100000 Json:[{ "Key":1,"Value":"a"},{ "Key":2,"Value":"bb"},{ "Key":3,"Value":"ccc"}]
        foreach (var g in group)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Count:{g.Count()} Json:{JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(g.Key)}");
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<AAA[]> GetValues()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "bb" },
            };
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "bb" },
            };
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "ccc" },
            };
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "bb" },
                new AAA { Key = 3, Value = "ccc" },
            };
        }
    }
}

class ArrayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IList<T>>
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _hashes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public bool Equals(IList<T> x, IList<T> y)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IList<T> obj)
    {
        var json = JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(obj);

        if (!_hashes.ContainsKey(json))
        {
            var hash = json.GetHashCode();

            if (!_hashes.ContainsValue(hash))
            {
                do
                {
                    hash++;
                } while (_hashes.ContainsValue(hash));
            }

            _hashes.Add(json, hash);
        }

        return _hashes[json];
    }
}
```

このコードは正しいですか？
また、もっと早くする方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public bool Equals(IList<T> x, IList<T> y)
> {
>     return true;
> }
> ```

このコードはあり得ません。[Object.GetHashCode() 継承時の注意](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx#Inheritors)や[クラスライブラリ開発のデザインガイドライン Equalsメソッドの実装](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx)を確認してください。

.NET 4で[StructuralComparisons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.collections.structuralcomparisons(v=vs.110).aspx)が追加されています。これを使うと要素の中身に応じた比較が簡単に記述できます。ただし、提供されるのは`IEqualityComparer`であって`IEqualityComparer<T>`ではないため`GroupBy`で要求されるインターフェースを実装する[クラスを用意](https://sayurin.blogspot.com/2011/07/istructuralequatable.html)する必要がある点と、`AAA`クラスの`Equals`が定義されていないためこのままではやはり比較できません。クラスでなく構造体にすると、全ての要素で比較されます。

```
public struct AAA
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var group = GetValues().GroupBy(x => x, new StructuralEqualityComparer<AAA[]>()).ToArray();

        // Count:200000 Json:[{ "Key":1,"Value":"a"},{ "Key":2,"Value":"bb"}]
        // Count:100000 Json:[{ "Key":1,"Value":"a"},{ "Key":2,"Value":"ccc"}]
        // Count:100000 Json:[{ "Key":1,"Value":"a"},{ "Key":2,"Value":"bb"},{ "Key":3,"Value":"ccc"}]
        foreach (var g in group)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Count:{g.Count()} Json:{JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(g.Key)}");
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<AAA[]> GetValues()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "bb" },
            };
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "bb" },
            };
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "ccc" },
            };
            yield return new AAA[]
            {
                new AAA { Key = 1, Value = "a" },
                new AAA { Key = 2, Value = "bb" },
                new AAA { Key = 3, Value = "ccc" },
            };
        }
    }
}

public class StructuralEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T: IStructuralEquatable {
    public bool Equals(T x, T y) {
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) {
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。返事が遅れて大変申し訳ございません。突如必要なくなって忘れていましたが大変勉強になりました。他の誰かの役に立つことを願います。